# How to stack multiple imageviews on top of eachother on my android layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Basically, I'm fairly new to android development and I'm trying to make an android layout that has at its center multiple images stacked on top of eachother. Each image must be able to rotate on itself independently from the others (which I've already achieved), and ideally the they would all share the same center. As it stands I have 4 such images (two ImageViews and two ProgressBars), but only the first two images on the list get centered, and the remaining images get scattered around the screen:

[This is how it looks in the preview, and how its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clwDv.png)

[This is how it actually looks like in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bexll.png)

And here's the XML for this part:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="760dp"
    android:layout_height="804dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.767">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="559dp"
        android:layout_height="521dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circlebar"
        tools:progress="60" />


    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="445dp"
            android:layout_height="503dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circleblue"
            tools:progress="80" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="454dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/pointerbig1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried everything I could think of to no avail. The first two elements seem to overlap just fine but the remaining ones will scatter and I'm unsure what's causing this. I've tried centering them in multiple ways, I've tried making it a FrameLayout and nothing will fix it.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ConstraintLayout` and add

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

to all of the child views. That way, it will make all views centered

Comment: I seem to have fixed it. The actual problem was the rotating animation was not centered on the image's center (even though it should've been), so the problem wasn't related to the XML at all. Nevertheless thank you so much for your help.